# Import Access data to SAS Enterprise Guide: without field length limitations

Tags: import, sas

The following code is supposed to import data from Access to SAS:

```
PROC IMPORT OUT=TEST 
            DATATABLE='Individual Profiles'
            DBMS=ACCESS REPLACE;
   DATABASE="E:\dummytext.accdb";
   USEDATE=YES;
   SCANTIME=NO;
   DBSASLABEL=NONE;
RUN;
DATA OUTPUT;
    SET TEST;
RUN;
```

Unfortunately the data is cut off. For example: The original Access variable contains 400 words but gets cut off at 77 words in SAS.

Comment: Try to use a LRECL=10000 option in your proc import: "When you use a fileref to specify a delimited file to import, the logical record length (LRECL) defaults to 256 unless you specify the LRECL in the filename statement. The maximum LRECL width that the IMPORT procedure supports is 32767."

Comment: @andrey_sz There is no LRECL for importing from access.  That only applies to text files.

Comment: @user3460365 Can you translate 'words' into 'characters'?  Is it cutting off at 200 characters long?

Comment: You mention you are using EG, can you use the IMPORT DATA task? or does this have to be coded for an external .sas file?